# Role based authorization access to JAX-WS web service methods

Tags: java, jax-ws

I would like to add a role based authorization feature in one of my web service application. It is powered by JAX-WS and Spring framework and it contains quite a number of web service methods. Some of the web service methods can only be accessed by certain role. Appreciate if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Spring-Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) if your project is already Spring based.